# RDF4J workbench cannot query new repositories

Tags: tomcat, rdf4j

I have a very simple setup, just rdf4j-server.war and rdf4j-workbench.war in a tomcat server.

I created a new repository and the new repository worked, so I could read and write from it via my program.

But when I used the workbench I could not query it. I could only see the summary site(nr of statements, nr of contexts) but the other buttons where greyed out. Interestingly I could query the system repository. After a little bit of just clicking around and not changing anything, suddenly it started working.

Did anyone else have the same issue or does anyone know what I might have clicked that it started working? Or was just some synching necessary before it started working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a caching bug. Should be fixed in the next release 2.2.2. While you wait for the next release you can force the cache to reset by restarting the browser.